# Python/Django json.loads() error when loading JSON File

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have the following directory structure:

```
project/build/contracts/MyFile.json
```

And I am writing code in the following directory

```
project/homeapp/views.py
```

In my `views.py` I have the following code:

```
with open("../build/contracts/MyFile.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    abi = data["abi"]
```

When I try to `python manage.py runserver` I get the following error:
[image]

The strange part is that I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I made a `viewstest.py` and placed the exact same code in it. When I run it with `python .\viewstest.py` and print the JSON to console, it works perfectly fine.

I even tried importing the `abi` variable from `viewstest.py` to `views.py` but got the same error. So I assume that it is an error relating to Django, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be **json.load()** and not **json.loads()**

Change the following code to:

```
with open("../build/contracts/MyFile.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    abi = data["abi"]
```

**Edit:**

Another alternative to get the path correct can be to use Pathlib.

```
from pathlib import Path

def your_view_func(request):
        current_dir = Path.cwd()
        file_loc = 'build/contracts/MyFile.json'
        
        with open(current_dir.joinpath(file_loc), 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            abi = data["abi"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it says No such file or directory: '/../build/contracts/MyFile.json'. I got this error before, is there something wrong with how my project is structured? Or how I'm passing the JSON file's directory to open() ?

Comment: Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: It's at the top of my original question :)

Comment: Change the directory location to:  /build/contracts/MyFile.json (remove the 2 dots)

Comment: Yes I tried this too, to no avail

Comment: Then try ./build/contracts/MyFile.json (only a single dot) [on my environment i am able to access my file]

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks! Can't believe I didn't try that before posting

Comment: It's fine! There is always a learning curve! Bon Voyage!